# Fast way to find the target from object array and merge together

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question detail object array with the question and question choices inside, like:

```
const questionDetail = [
    {
        question: {
            questionId: 1,
        },
        choices: [
            {
                choiceId: 1,
                questionId: 1,
            },
            {
                choiceId: 2,
                questionId: 1,
            },
            {
                choiceId: 3,
                questionId: 1,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        question: {
            questionId: 2,
        },
        choices: [
            {
                choiceId: 5,
                questionId: 2,
            },
            {
                choiceId: 6,
                questionId: 2,
            },
            {
                choiceId: 7,
                questionId: 2,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        question: {
            questionId: 3,
        },
        choices: [
            {
                choiceId: 1,
                questionId: 3,
            },
            {
                choiceId: 2,
                questionId: 3,
            },
            {
                choiceId: 3,
                questionId: 3,
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

And another response object array is:

```
const response = [
    {
        responseId: 1,
        questionId: 1,
        choiceId: 2,
    },
    {
        responseId: 2,
        questionId: 3,
        choiceId: 8,
    },
]
```

I want to merge these two together into one array, so I can see question, choice and response from one array.

This is what I have tried:

```
const merged = questionDetail.map((questionDetailItem) => {
    const { questionId } = questionDetailItem.question
    const choices = questionDetailItem.choices
    const responseFiltered = response.find((responseItem) => {
        return responseItem.questionId === questionId
    })
    return {
        question: questionDetailItem.question,
        choices,
        response: responseFiltered,
    }
})
```

I use `Array.prototype.find()` to find the target item, however, it will loop the entire array including the one I have checked before. Is there a faster way to replace the `find` method? So I can skip the one I have checked and not go through the entire array?

Answer (score 1):

This is example about search item in array object by `key array`

```js
var pattern = [
    'l' => [
        '5' => 's'
    ],
      'm' => [
        '2' => [
            'k' => 'a'
       ],
        'u' => [
            '5' => 's',
            'l' => [
                't' => [
                    's' => '5',
                    'p' => 'w'
                ],
                'p' => 'w'
            ]
        ],
        's' => []
    ],
    'n' => [
        '5' => 's'
    ]
];

var parameter = ['m', 'u', 'l', 't', 's'];

searchObjectByArrayKey(pattern, parameter)

// function searchObjectByArrayKey
function searchObjectByArrayKey(s, h, g = 0) {
    if (g == h.length - 1) {
        s = s.splice(h.length - 1, 1);
        return s;
    }
    w = g;
    for (var k in s) {
        if (Array.isArray(s[k]) && s[k].length > 0) {
            if (k == h[g]) {
                // processing
                console.log(s[k]);
                // end processing
                w++;
            }
            if (w != g) return searchObjectByArrayKey(s, h, w);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct an object or Map mapping the `response` items by their `questionId` first.

```
const responsesById = Object.fromEntries(
    response.map(obj => [obj.questionId, obj])
);
const merged = questionDetail.map((questionDetailItem) => {
    const { questionId } = questionDetailItem.question;
    const { choices } = questionDetailItem;
    return {
        question: questionDetailItem.question,
        choices,
        response: responsesById[questionId],
    }
});
```